# requirement traceabilty in gitlab

Tags: testing, gitlab, issue-tracking, traceability, requirements-management

In the gitlab documents https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/requirements/ it is written that "The ability to add and edit a requirement’s long description introduced in GitLab 13.5., and  Moved under Issues in 14.4  https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/merge_requests/70748?_gl=1*1q8gjjj*_ga*MTYwNTIwODgzMy4xNjYzMDUwMzcy*_ga_ENFH3X7M5Y*MTY2Mzc0OTA0Ni4xNy4xLjE2NjM3NTA0MDkuMC4wLjA.
But for my project, I can not see the requirement feature on gitlab. Where and how can I find or add that feature in my project and how can I trace the requirements with test cases?

Answer (score 0):

The requirement is only available in GitLab Ultimate self-managed and GitLab Ultimate SaaS.

Comment: How can I know if I am using GitLab Ultimate self-managed or GitLab Ultimate SaaS?

Comment: Are you working on gitlab.com (Saas) or on a self hosted service? https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/subscriptions/